# How to create and run and algorithm/script on Power Platform?

Tags: power-platform

I am looking at ways to bring an Excel Spreadsheet, which uses lots of Visual Basic Access code - onto the Power Platform. The purpose of it to do Forecasting and Optimisation algotithms.

What is the best way to re-create this code?

I am thinking that we move all the data from the spreadsheet into Dataverse. It seems the only option to run the code is to put it into an Azure Function?

Is there a way to do this another way, through AI Builder or Power Automate? Could this be ran through Power Fx - or is Power Fx limited to basic instructions?

It seems limited in the way we can run code through Power Platform... any help or advice is appreciated.

Todd

Answer (score 0):

I dont think a 1:1 copy paste action is possible (because of that VB access code).
Although Dataverse is a relational database it supports most common database functionalities. And if it is simple data (and not too much of it) you could alternatively use SharePoint lists. This is often simpler, and less expensive in licenses.
Also Power Automate can be used for automatically updating data in DV or Lists.
So if you manage to get you data into on of these two, the "Power Platform way" would be to expose it using Power BI.

It can be a overhvelming undertaking if you are not familliar with PP at all. And I would advise you to see if it is possible to slice it into smaller chuncks and try it out one small bit a a time.